# how to update menu item title in onMenuItemClick()

Tags: android

I have created cardview as single item of `RecyclerView`
and in my `cardview`, I have created a popup menu programmatically..

I want to change the title of menu item at run-time

is it possible to update menu item title in `onMenuItemClick()` method?

My `HomeFragment.java` looks like-

```
 private void showPopupMenu(View view, int position,String post_key) {

    // inflate menu
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(),view );
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.card_view_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener(position,post_key));
    popup.show();
}


class MyMenuItemClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

private int position;
DatabaseReference mPostDatabase;
private String post_key;
Menu menu;

 MyMenuItemClickListener(int positon,String post_key) {
    this.position = positon;
    this.post_key=post_key;
    mPostDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");
}


@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(final MenuItem item) {

    int id=item.getItemId();

    switch (id){

        case R.id.delete_post:

          mPostDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
              @Override
              public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                  if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(post_key)){

                      String from_id= String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child(post_key).child("from").getValue());

                      if(from_id.equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())){

                          mPostDatabase.child(post_key).removeValue();
                      }
                      else {

                      //here i want to change the title              
                      item.setTitle("Save Post");//it doesn't work
                      }
                  }
              }

              @Override
              public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

              }
          });

    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: If you mean you want the menu item's title to be different the next time it shows, then, yeah, that's not going to work. You'll need to modify the menu right before you show it. If you want to change the title on a single item, then it should work in your `showPopupMenu()` method after you've inflated it.  There are other ways to handle that, though; e.g., by loading a different `R.menu` with the appropriate item, or hiding/showing separate items the relevant items in a single menu.

Comment: try item.setTitle("new Title")

Comment: Thanks for your help!....actually in my app i want to enable a user to delete the post which he/she had posted.. not delete the posts which others have posted....so i want to enable current user only to save other's post...that is why..here i need to update the item's title...hopes you are getting me...so, how can i modify the post title? Thanks!!

Comment: @ZaidMirza I have tried..but it doesn't work...look the code above

Answer (score 0):

after this line :

```
//here i want to change the title              
item.setTitle("Save Post");
```

call below function

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```